# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Contract')

Tags: contract-development, etherscan, smart-contract-wallets, polygon

Trying to create a smart contract but keep getting a error for "bytecode" parameter. Using Local: 800 to run the code on google chrome browser. Can I get help fixing this issue ??

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Although the complete code is not visible and according to my observation, you are missing the web3.js package so before this script you can add

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@latest/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
```